# Copy pointer address for conditional breakpoint from Visual Studio watch window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch-window

Is there a quicker way to copypaste C++ pointers from Visual Studio's Watch window into a conditional breakpoint?

*Context:* My pointer values change each time I restart my application, so I need to update the address in my conditional breakpoint.

If I have a watch for `this`, copypasting it gives something like this:

`+      this    0x000001287234a8c0 {mTick=2994 mTime=0.00000000 ...}    AnimComponent *`

When I right click on `this`, there's a "Copy Value" option, but it copies that `{}` block too:

`0x000001287234a8c0 {mTick=2994 mTime=0.00000000 ...}`

So my current process to copy my `this` watch's pointer value:

- Click on `this`
- Ctrl-C
- Edit conditional breakpoint
- Ctrl-v, remove the `{}` block, and add a == after `this`

*I'm using C++, so I can't use the ["Make Object ID" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022#bkmk_objectIds).*

Comment: Just click on variable value in the Watch window, it will leave only `0x000001287234a8c0`, then copy it.

Comment: @273K: That sounds like something that used to work, but neither clicking nor double clicking on anything in the Value column makes it an editable number field. I'm using VS 2017.

Comment: Left click? You used right clicks in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Watch Window

Use `(void*)this` in the watch window to prevent the `{}` block and make "Copy Value" copy only the number.

## Keyboard Shortcut

Open Tools > Customize > Keyboard

Search for "CopyValue" and you should find DebuggerContextMenus.AutosWindow.CopyValue. Map a keyboard shortcut to it and you can copy values with only two steps: click + keyboard.

If you use Ctrl-Shift-C to copy, be sure to remove that shortcut from View.ClassView or it will interrupt your copying.